# React JS sorting issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to sort some data in my application. I'd like to support the following options:

- Price (low to high)
- Price (high to low)
- Mileage (low to high)
- Mileage (high to low)

It looks like price sorting is working. However, when I click on "lowest mileage", it keeps showing the highest price results - the old value of `sorting`. I tried `useEffect`, but I couldn't make it work. Here's my code:

`App.js`

```js
      
      const [carList, setCarList] = useState(cars)
      const [sorting, setSorting] = useState("pricelow")
      
      const handleSort = (e) => {
        setSorting(e.target.value)
        if (sorting === "pricelow"){
          const newlist = carList.sort((a,b) => {
            return parseInt(b.carPrice) - parseInt(a.carPrice)
          })
          setCarList(newlist)
        }
        if (sorting === "pricehigh"){
          const newlist = carList.sort((a,b) => {
            return parseInt(a.carPrice) - parseInt(b.carPrice)
          })
          setCarList(newlist)
        }
        if (sorting === "kmlow"){
          const newlist = carList.sort((a,b) => {
            return parseInt(a.carMileage) - parseInt(b.carMileage)
          })
          setCarList(newlist)
        }
      }
```

`AdsList.js`

```js
      <select className="form-select w-25" onChange={handleSort} value={sorting}>
          <option value="pricelow">Sort By Lowest Price</option>
          <option value="pricehigh">Sort By Highest Price</option>
          <option value="kmlow">Sort By Lowest Km</option>
          <option value="kmhigh">Sort By Highest Km</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Can you also add `carList` data?

Comment: sure hold on please

Comment: added in code .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the `setSorting` doesn't change the `sorting` value straight away but rather waits until the component re-renders. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Do this instead:

```js
 const [sorting, setSorting] = useState("pricelow")
  
  const handleSort = (e) => {
    const sortValue = e.target.value;
    setSorting(sortValue)
    
    if (sortValue === "pricelow"){
      const newlist = carList.sort((a,b) => {
        return parseInt(b.carPrice) - parseInt(a.carPrice)
      })
      setCarList(newlist)
    }
    if (sortValue === "pricehigh"){
      const newlist = carList.sort((a,b) => {
        return parseInt(a.carPrice) - parseInt(b.carPrice)
      })
      setCarList(newlist)
    }
    if (sortValue === "kmlow"){
      const newlist = carList.sort((a,b) => {
        return parseInt(a.carMileage) - parseInt(b.carMileage)
      })
      setCarList(newlist)
    }
  }
```

Another tip, use a `switch/case` for cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

setSort function will not set the value instantly.
it only changes the value on it next render

best method is to use  useEffect hook

```
  const [carList, setCarList] = useState(cars)
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState("pricelow")
  useEffect(()=> {
    if (sorting === "pricelow"){
      const newlist = carList.sort((a,b) => {
        return parseInt(b.carPrice) - parseInt(a.carPrice)
      })
      setCarList(newlist)
    }
    if (sorting === "pricehigh"){
      const newlist = carList.sort((a,b) => {
        return parseInt(a.carPrice) - parseInt(b.carPrice)
      })
      setCarList(newlist)
    }
    if (sorting === "kmlow"){
      const newlist = carList.sort((a,b) => {
        return parseInt(a.carMileage) - parseInt(b.carMileage)
      })
      setCarList(newlist)
    }
  },[sorting])





<select className="form-select w-25" onChange={(e)=>setSorting(e.target.value)} value={sorting}>
      <option value="pricelow">Sort By Lowest Price</option>
      <option value="pricehigh">Sort By Highest Price</option>
      <option value="kmlow">Sort By Lowest Km</option>
      <option value="kmhigh">Sort By Highest Km</option>
  </select>
```